# How can I preserve trailing tab character in Nano?

Tags: nano

I do have `set autoindent` in `~/.nanorc`, and it is auto-indenting as expected as I type. The issue I'm having is that any blank lines containing tab characters have those tabs stripped as trailing whitespace. Is there anything I can do to allow those tabs to be preserved?

Let's say I'm writing the following C program:

```c
#include <stdio>

int main(int argc, char** args) {

    printf("Hello World!\n");

    // I want to add something after this comment

    return 0;
}
```

Imagine that I decide to add another expression after `printf("Hello World!\n");`

I move my cursor to the line I wish to start writing at and realize that I'm not indented correctly anymore. I want to stop nano from stripping the trailing whitespace, specifically tab characters.

Comment: Taking the whitespace back out when you complete a line with only whitespace in auto-indent mode is currently hardcoded in nano: https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/nano.git/tree/src/text.c?id=33e882e6f89097462d15d945a37e8a72ff69986a#n889

Comment: Maybe equally as useful would be a way to just put them back if you move the cursor back to that line (unfortunately idk if that's possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current solution is disabling `autoindent`.

In response to the following comment I tested nano's behavior with the `autoindent` option enabled and disabled:

> Taking the whitespace back out when you complete a line with only
> whitespace in auto-indent mode is currently hardcoded in nano: 
> [git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/nano.git/tree/src/…](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/nano.git/tree/src/text.c?id=33e882e6f89097462d15d945a37e8a72ff69986a#n889) – [rakslice](https://superuser.com/users/31972/rakslice)

When `autoindent` is not set, the trailing tabs will not be removed.